# Why did Google develop a cross-compiler from Java to JavaScript?

Tags: java, web-development, javascript, web-applications

Google developed a cross-compiler from Java to JavaScript. Why did they do this? Does this mean that JavaScript is not good enought for developing advanced web apps?

Comment: I honestly believe Google must answer it. Be specific with the question.

Comment: because it is easier to find Java developers then ones for JavaScript. =P

Comment: If JavaScript wasn't good enough, wouldn't they convert to something else?

Comment: I counter your question with "Why not?".

Comment: Urp... I initally read the title as "Why did Google cross the road?"

Comment: Because the existing "Run Java code in a browser"-solution was not what they needed?

Answer (score 7):

They provide part of the answer on this page:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/makinggwtbetter.html

> To start with the basics, why does GWT exist in the first place? The
>   short answer is that GWT exists to make the web better for users.
>   We've infused a slightly longer answer into our mission statement:
>
> > GWT's mission is to radically improve the web experience for users by
> >     enabling developers to use existing Java tools to build no-compromise
> >     AJAX for any modern browser.

In other words, it was a way of getting Java developers to write Ajax-heavy apps.

Comment: Another relevant quote from the same page: "We chose the Java language primarily because there already are so many great tools out there, not to mention scads of books, articles, libraries, and expertise"

Answer (score 4):

Because at the time, people didn't see any value in learning JavaScript, JavaScript lacked a large implementation base (though it's got the largest install base out there!), and in general Java programmers seem to prefer programming in Java more than anything else.

Comment: I still can't get grasp people _enjoy_ writing JS.

Comment: I still can't grasp people enjoying writing Java.

Comment: Different strokes for different folks, I guess.

Comment: I enjoy writing JS, not because of the language, it is horrible. But considering how much better it can make a web app the results are often very rewarding.

Comment: I work with different toolkits in Ajax, GWT, YUI, jQuery.  I like them for different reasons, GWT has other features besides no js and cross browser compatibility, but I like working with js as well.  I like working with js and without it, depending on the context of the work.

Comment: It isn't JavaScript that people don't like, it is dealing with the crappy DOM model and all the different DOM implementations and browser incompatibilities. JavaScript in and of itself is a good language, it is a shame its most popular and well known implementations are tied to browsers and the DOM.

Comment: I enjoy JS... Many of its critics on the 'net never learned it properly, they would fall apart in strict-mode.  Others have their genuine reasons, mostly regarding the prototypal model.  Coming from years of Delphi, C# and C++, I honestly prefer the prototypal model over traditional class-based inheritance.  JS+frameworks allows me to do big complex stuff really quickly and with simple/small programs.  Half my time in Delphi was spent writing boilerplate, given the lack of either generics/templates.

Comment: Don't write in Java, and don't write in JavaScript. Write in Scala!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - trust me, there's plenty of people that don't like JS the language itself. It has very poor structure compared to many languages out there. Last time I wanted to extend someone else's JS classes I had to pick them apart, figure out how they were implementing "classes", copy their method of "extending" them, etc. In Java to extend someone's classes you don't even need to see their class' source. Just write 'extends TheirClass'. It has a much more usable and uniform structure for things which allows that level of simplicity in classes working together and being modular.

Comment: @JimboJonny - your "argument" is full of [logical fallacies](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/). Anecdotal; X is bad because of one example of someone misusing it? Compositional; Java is better because of one small part so the entire language is better? Wow, you told me, not.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - You implied that there aren't people that dislike JS. I simply stated there are people that do and gave one example why some would feel that way (which would be that the concept of self-contained class based programming doesn't work properly in JS, only hacked class programming that does not fully fulfill the concept of what self contained class programming is actually for). How is that a *fallacy*? You asserted a negative, I gave an example contrary to it. To imply I need to more than that in order to show that some people would dislike JS is, ironically, actually a fallacy.

Answer (score 4):

Java is a compiled language with a variety of mature tools and a large developer community. It has types, objects, exceptions, frameworks, great tools, community support, etc.

[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) has all of these things too - *except for the compilation*.

If you could compile your code, thoroughly test it in Java and then translate it to something the client can run (i.e. JavaScript - I'm guessing VBScript had no chance here) then it'll reduce the overall development costs. Developing large, complex AJAX applications like GMail is expensive.

There are many "write in one language, run in another" techniques around - but this was a good one.

*UPDATE*

To clarify my point further, JavaScript is an interpreted language where the parser will check syntax, but not pick up semantic errors such as:

```
function f(x) {
  g(y);
}
```

where neither 'g()' nor 'y' exist. This will only be picked up at runtime.

There are many **[JavaScript Engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine)** such as [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29), [Nitro (JavaScriptCore)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore) and [Spider/Jaeger/TraceMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey) which will do a fantastic job of parsing and running the parsed code as fast as possible (perhaps by emitting machine code), but won't catch the semantic errors that a full compilation process would. This is often because scripts are delivered to the web browser independently of each other and the JavaScript Engine doesn't have the whole story until all of the required scripts have been downloaded/cached, the DOM has been initialised and any dynamically-generated scripts have been triggered. So the engine normally cannot have the whole source until quite late in the download and render process.

A full compiler will highlight the above code snippet as an error, which is one motivation to use a compiled language, verify correctness, perform unit tests and then use reflection or decompilation to generate the verified-correct JavaScript to run on the client.

Comment: "JavaScript has many of these things except for the compilation. – Huh? First off, this doesn't even make sense. JavaScript is a language. A language is an abstract set of mathematical rules. Languages aren't compiled or interpreted. They just are. Compilation and interpretation are traits of the implementation, i.e. the compiler or interpreter (duh!), not the language. Every language can be implemented by a compiler and an interpreter. Most languages have both compiled and interpreted implementations. Most modern high-performance implementations combine both.

Comment: And secondly: Can you name *one*, just *one* JavaScript implementation without a compiler? I don't know of any. At least not a widely used one. Certainly not one of the ones that are shipped with any of the popular browsers, those all have compilers.

Comment: JavaScript runtimes are better than statically compiled runtimes in many ways, every one worth using has a very optimized JIT compiler and runtime that has way more potential than any statically compiled system does. Your *answer* is still wrong, as that *may* be perfectly fine JavaScript. Also GMail isn't written with GWT.